# Minimum of sum of six squares over a polytope

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_6^2\\ \text{subject to} & x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_6 = K\\ & x_1 + x_2 \ge k_1\\ & x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 \ge k_2\\ & x_1 \ge x_2 \ge x_3 \ge x_4 \ge x_5 \ge x_6 \ge 0\end{array}$$

Comment: What have you tried?What techniques do you know? No one can help till they know what you know already. No one will just write out an answer for you of course. Doing that really will not help you at all.

Comment: Paul is being fair, but this is pretty easy to solve by inspection. For instance: is there any reason to believe that $x_1\neq x_2$, or $x_3\neq x_4$, or $x_5\neq x_6$? And is there any reason to believe that $x_1+x_2>k_1$, strictly? etc.